# ReactJS | Что значит useEffect и как его использовать?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я написал лёгкую программу, которая использует `useState` и `useEffect`, это просто счётчик времени, который сам себя обновляет каждую секунду. Но я не очень хорошо понимаю зачем нужен `useEffect`. И даже так, я хотел попробовать написать такой счётчик времени. Я использовал документацию **React**, и дополнил его этими `use.....`. Объясните пожалуйста значение `useEffect` и уместно ли использовать его в моём коде?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const Clock = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setDate(new Date().toLocaleTimeString())
    }, 1000)
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Привет, мир!</h1>
      <h2>Сейчас {date}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Clock;
```

(Код работает как надо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать useEffect стоит, например, для запросов:

```
function EffectExample() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  async function takeData() {
    const data = await fetch('какой-нибудь url');
    setData(data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    takeData();
  }, []);

  return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
}
```

Здесь, если вызывать `takeData` без useEffect, произойдет либо бесконечное количество запросов к серверу, либо `infinite loop error`, так как обновление состояния `data` будет рендерить компонент заново, что в свою очередь заново вызывет функцию `takeData`, которая вновь обновит `data` и так далее до бесконечности. С useEffect же `takedData` вызывается только один раз после после первого рендера.

Comment: Не надо так писать `useEffect(async() => {` . Переместите функцию `takeData` внутрь  `useEffect` -а.

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов, мне кажется стоит оставить как есть, иногда бывают такие ситуации, что нужно вызвать несколько функций в одном useEffect

Comment: Нельзя так делать. *However, an effect hook should return nothing or a clean up function. That's why using async directly in the useEffect function isn't allowed.* https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326, https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data

Comment: @Voprositel, так а нет проблемы их вызывать без `useEffect(async () => ...)`. Сделайте IIFE внутри юзЕффекта и вызывайте хоть 100

Comment: @entithat, понятно, поправил, спасибо за объяснение

Answer (score 3):

`useEffect` - это то, что выполнится сразу после рендера Вашего компонента. Вы запускаете `setTimeout` после рендера кода, и начинает считаться счетчик, который записывает в useState новую информацию, и она выводится в компоненте.

Все верно.